# Get local IP in a recommend way

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in kotlin an android.
In my app I want to get the ip of the mobile in wifi network and display it.

```
fun runDvr(view: View) {        
        GetMyIP_A();
    }
```

My options:
1)

```
private fun GetMyIP_A() {
        val wm = applicationContext.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val ipAddress: String = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.connectionInfo.ipAddress)
        Log.i("TAG", "IP: $ipAddress")
        }
```

This works but formatIpAddress is deprecated.
I would like to use InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress instead

2)

```
private fun GetMyIP_B() {
   val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        executor.execute {
            val str = InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress
            Log.i("TAG", "IP: $str")


            handler.post {
                val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.TextBoxA)
                editText.text.clear();
                editText.text.append(str);
                
            }
        }
   }
```

This works also, but I would like to use a coroutine to create a thread.

3)

```
 private fun GetMyIP_C() {


     // Start a coroutine
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val str = InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress
           Log.i("TAG", "IP: $str")
        }

    }
```

This works, but I heard it is not recommend to use GlobalScope

4)

```
 private fun GetMyIP_D() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
        launch { // launch a new coroutine in the scope of runBlocking
            
           val str = InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress;
           Log.i("TAG", "IP: $str")
        }
        
        Log.i("TAG",  "Back in GetMyIP_D")
    }
```

This does not work (InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress; is not allowed in a blocking fun) and it would blocked my main thread. How to lunch a coroutine without blocking?
What is the recommend way to use InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress?

Comment: Do you only want the IP of the Wi-Fi network? What if you are connected to cellular, would you like the IP of that as well if that's the case?

Comment: It is only for me to learn and understand how to use InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress.
I guess a coroutine is recommend to use with it, but I'm not sure.

However I have to show the IP address in my app, because a httpServer is running in the app and the user should know the address.
So in my case I need it with WifFi and maybe when the user use an VPN connection to his home network.

Comment: Hi Klaas, thanks for the feedback. I suppose why I am confused is I'm wondering if you want the ip of your local android device or the ip of the network that the device is connected to? If it's the latter, you would actually use a different API.

Comment: I want the local IP address of my local device, because the server is running on my local device too. Then i want to open the web site from my pc. The user should see the needed web address in my app